# How to force reconnecting with Fabric

Tags: python, ssh, fabric, paramiko, reconnect

I'm using python fabric.
Each time I'm changing something to the FreeBSD pf firewall, the existing connection of Fabric dies or hangs, or I don't know but it doesnt't work anymore and the script hangs.
Usually ssh connections are more robust than that, sometimes they hang for a few seconds when you change something with the firewall, but with fabric, they just hang forever, and the script is rendered useless.
Anyway, even if my ssh connection dies, I'd like Fabric to create a new SSH connection to continue with the other `run` commands of my script.
It's a problem with Fabric. I used countless other tools based on SSH in the past, including my own and I didn't have this problem.
How can I disconnect, and reconnect fabric ssh connection pool? Or set all the connections to expire and force them to reconnect.

It would be better if the `run` function just detected after a few seconds that the connection no longer works and create a new one, but apparently Fabric doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that:

```
from fabric import network
from fabric.state import connections

def reconnect_current_host():
    network.disconnect_all()
    connections.connect(env.host + ':%s' % env.port)
```

It's ugly but it seems to be working for my particular script that I use with only one host at a time.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  I ran into this problem because my script makes a configuration change that only takes effect on the next login.